# Shifting a matrix

Tags: c++, shift

I'm using this function to shift elements of a matrix.
To do this I'm shifting between 1-3 quadrant and 2nd-4th .
It works good for even values of N ,but with odd N it doesn't work for last elements.
I need to use this shift because I have to use after the fourier transform

```
void ftshifting(double **filter,int rows,int cols){
    int r2,c2,tmp1_3,tmp2_4;
    r2 = rows/2;
    c2 = cols/2;
    for (int i = 0; i<r2; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k<c2; k++){
            tmp1_3 = filter[i][k];
            filter[i][k] = filter[i+r2][k+c2];
            filter[i+r2][k+c2] = tmp1_3;
            tmp2_4 = filter[i+r2][k];
            filter[i+r2][k] = filter[i][k+c2];
            filter[i][k+c2] = tmp2_4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the desired output be for a 3 x 3 matrix: `{[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]}` where each row is in `[ ... ]`?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html

Comment: if you expect help you should be willing to write out 9 simple numbers, i. e. the expected output of the 3x3 matrix rather than merely post a link. but then if you were willing to exercise your mind a little bit you wouldn't be here with a trivial question anyways. good luck feeding off the spoon.

Comment: I m sorry but what I have to do is obtain the same work of that function for this I wrote that. It was : {[9 2 7], [4 5 6], [3 8 1]}

Comment: good job! i think the answer below is correct and will do what you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you're trying to do I think you need to change these lines:

```
r2 = rows/2;
c2 = cols/2;
```

to this:

```
r2 = (rows+1)/2;
c2 = (cols+1)/2;
```

So in an odd matrix, the middle row and column will be ignored rather than the last row and column.

**Update**

Having said that, your loops will then be going too far in the odd case, so you'll still need to use the original rows/2 and cols/2 for the loop range.

```
for (int i = 0; i<rows/2; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k<cols/2; k++){
```

For reference, here's what the whole function would look like with updates:

```
void ftshifting(double **filter,int rows,int cols){
    int r2,c2,tmp1_3,tmp2_4;
    r2 = (rows+1)/2;
    c2 = (cols+1)/2;
    for (int i = 0; i<rows/2; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k<cols/2; k++){
            tmp1_3 = filter[i][k];
            filter[i][k] = filter[i+r2][k+c2];
            filter[i+r2][k+c2] = tmp1_3;
            tmp2_4 = filter[i+r2][k];
            filter[i+r2][k] = filter[i][k+c2];
            filter[i][k+c2] = tmp2_4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks. I don t know if I can vote for something for you